# i want insert a div block which is created using template letrals inside another template letrals div

Tags: javascript, html

I have created multiple template literals `<div>` blocks like this:

```js
let title = `<div class = prod_detail_${each_response_obj.id} id=${each_response_obj.id}>
                        <p class = prod_title> Title : ${each_response_obj.title} </p> <br>
                    </div>`;
```

I have a parent `<div>` which is also created using template literals:

```js
let product_div = `<div class=${each_response_obj.handle} id=${each_response_obj.id}_product>   </div>
```

Now I want to insert `title` inside `product_div`. I tried, but I couldn't find any solution.

Comment: Can you add more details about the value you need to set to your `div` title attribute? And better to add the code you've tried and didn't work?

Answer (score 1):

Is that what you mean?

```js
let each_response_obj = {
    id:"1",
    title:"a",
    handle:"c"
}
let title = `<div class = prod_detail_${each_response_obj.id} id=${each_response_obj.id}> <p class = prod_title> Title : ${each_response_obj.title} </p> <br> </div>`
let product_div = `<div class=${each_response_obj.handle} id=${each_response_obj.id}_product> ${title}</div>`
console.log(product_div)
```

But it works fine

Comment: It's best practice to add quotation marks around attribute values. Like this: `class="prod_detail_${each_response_obj.id}"`.